# Quotient group $G/G_0$ in Group Topology

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

I'm stuck on this (apparently) simple thing:

If $G$ is a topological group and $G_0$ is the connected component of $G$ containing the identity then $G/G_0$ is discrete if and only if $G_0$ is open.

Can you help me to figure out why?
Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quotient group $G/G_0$ is discrete if and only if singleton sets are open, which is the case if and only if the unit element singleton is open. The preimage of the unit element singleton of $G/G_0$ under the canonical projection is $G_0$.

Comment: Ok thank you! The problem I had was caused by the fact that I thought that "Discrete Group" = "Countable Group", but it means "Group equipped with the discrete topology" instead :-)

Comment: Hi Daniel I dont understand "which is the case if and only if the unit element singleton is open." If you have time can you explain this in simple terms? Or is it better i write a new question for this?

Comment: @JKnecht If all singleton sets are open, then in particular the singleton containing the unit (identity) element is open. That's not particular to topological groups. Since every set is a union of singletons, a space in which all singletons are open is discrete. Conversely, in a discrete space all subsets are open, hence in particular the singleton sets. For the other direction, we note that in a topological group $G$ the left translation $\lambda_a \colon x \mapsto ax$ is a homeomorphism for all $a\in G$, and hence $\{a\} = \lambda_a(\{e\})$ is open if $\{e\}$ is open.

Comment: So in a topological group, either all singleton sets are open (and the topology is discrete), or no singleton set is open. Typically, the singleton most easy to check is $\{e\}$. When we are dealing with a quotient group $G/G_0$, the preimage of the identity element of $G/G_0$ under the canonical projection is $G_0$, so if we endow $G/G_0$ with the quotient topology, the identity singleton in $G/G_0$ is open if and only if $G_0$ is open in $G$.